# Adding variable at the end of URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, variables

So far I have done

jQuery:

```
function addURL(element)
{
var baseZipCode = 48180;
$(element).attr('href', function() {
    return this.href + baseZipCode;
});
}
```

html:

```
<a onclick="addURL(this)" href="http://www.weather.com/weather/today/" target="_blank">Click this</a>
```

My problem is when user clicks on link and the new window open everything is ok, but when the user clicks on the link again without a refresh, the variable is added twice to the link.

For example:

First time:
http://www.weather.com/weather/today/48180

Second time:
http://www.weather.com/weather/today/4818048180

It doesn't act right until you do a page refresh, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `addURL` function with

```
function addURL(element)
{
    var baseZipCode = '48180';
    if (element.href.slice(-baseZipCode.length) !== baseZipCode){
        element.href += baseZipCode;
    }
}
```

there is no jQuery involved..

Comment: +1 Nicely done, jQuery not needed. Is it better to check for existence first then add or [just add then replace duplicates (lazy)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15907240/144665)?

Comment: @iambriansreed, more of a preference.. the only benefit to checking is that you can specify where to check, whereas just replacing the duplicate could (*very unlikely in this scenario*) replace another *match* in the original string..

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with [`jQuery.fn.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Javascript:

```
  jQuery("a").one("click", function(){ // Set a handler that execute once
        var baseZipCode = 48180;
        this.href += baseZipCode; //same as "this.href = this.href + baseZipCode"
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.weather.com/weather/today/" target="_blank">Click this</a>
```

Maybe you will need to add some class to <a> tags to differ it from another ones

Comment: +1 Not sure if the answer applies but `jQuery.fn.one` is a new one to me.

Comment: Sometimes `jQuery.fn.one` is very useful.. Instead of test each user click you will just execute handler on first click.. I think it is a good solution in this case..

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
function addURL(element)
{
    var baseZipCode = 48180;
    element.href = (element.href + baseZipCode)
        .replace(baseZipCode + baseZipCode, baseZipCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.href.indexOf(baseZipCode) != -1 ? this.href : this.href + baseZipCode;
```

Comment: Guess this is not the case but if `baseZipCode` is already contained in the link it would fail. You will be better using `slice(-baseZipCode.length)` to check if it is contained at the end of the stirng

Comment: sure but u would be really unlucky to find your zip code elsewhere than where you put it

Comment: This worked perfectly because I am passing the zipcode as a request attribute. Thanks

Comment: @mlwacosmos Hey, once I changed my variable to a string, the zipcode started repeating again, for example I changed var zipcode = 48180 to var zipcode = '48180'. If you can, can you explain why your suggestion doesn't work anymore

Comment: @mlwacosmos I fixed it, I just put the value of the variable in this.href.indexOf() instead of the variable name